# Не отрабатывает flex

Tags: html, css

Есть 3 блока div заключенные в div. У этого div прописал:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

У трех блоков ничего не прописано. Почему они не сжимаются?

```
<div class="footer_row">
            <div class="footer_logo">
                <img src='\images\logo_footer.png'>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_contacts">
                <div class="footer__name">
                    <h4 class="footer_h">Связаться с нами</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="footer_email">
                    офрвфв
                </div>
                <div class="footer_number">
                    824г1
                </div>
                <div class="footer_address">
                   345
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_social">
                <div class="footer_name">
                    Мы в соцсетях
                </div>
                <div class="footer_networks">
                    <div class="footer_instagram">

                    </div>
                    <div class="footer_vk">

                    </div>
                    <div class="footer_facebook">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer__social__rem" >
                   ловрафф
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

у footer_row прописал флекс

Comment: А с какой стати они должны сжиматься?

Comment: я же прописал свойство flex

Comment: не сжиматься, а вниз опускать элемент, если не влазит

Comment: Html в студию или пример где-нибудь на codepen

Comment: добавил код html

Comment: @Александр так может все влазит? :)

Comment: при адаптации надо)там картинки будут, которые точно не влезут, я и хотел чтобы эти div выстроились в столбец

Answer (score 0):

попробуй дописать `justify-content: space-between;`